# ADF Dataflow : Query about transformation

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to transform source data using ADF Dataflow.

My source data is as under:

### Id,Name,Direction

123, ABC, North

123, ABC, South

123, ABC, East

123, ABC, West

I want the output to be:

### Id,Name,Direction1,Direction2,Direction3,Direction4

123, ABC, North, South, East, West

What if there are more than one column which has multiple values.

For e.g. Source data is

### Id,Name,Direction,Status

123, ABC, North, A

123, ABC, South, B

123, ABC, East, C

123, ABC, West, D

I want the output to be:

### Id,Name,Direction1,Direction2,Direction3,Direction4, Status1, Status2, Status3, Status4

123, ABC, North, South, East, West, A,B,C,D

Can this be done in ADF Dataflow?

I have tried the pivot transformation in ADF Dataflow but unable to crack the logic.

Thx in advance,

Comment: Can you please share the outcome of the pivot transformation? You should be able to achieve at least -> Id,Name,Direction1,Direction2,Direction3,Direction4 with that.

Comment: Thx Yash for your time.
How do I achieve even

Id,Name,Direction1,Direction2,Direction3,Direction4

As I am not using any aggregate functions.

Comment: You say you tried pivot transformation but couldn't get it to work. I am keen to see what you tried, its output and why you were unsuccessful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `collect(column)` aggregate function in two pivot transformations for two columns.

Please follow the below demonstration to get the desired result(**only in this case**).

Use two pivot transformations for Direction and status columns.

**Direction column:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Status column:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Use **join** transformation to combine the above two.

[image]

For some reasons it is giving errors when loading it to sink file as csv. So, use sink cache and download the result from preview.

[image]

[image]

**Downloaded result:**

[image]